# Calculate interrater reliability for multiple trials and raters in R

Tags: r, agreement-statistics

I have data for a large number of `Trial`s (only three shown here) and ratings by subjects `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`(many more in the actual data). In each `Trial` subjects were asked to determine whether event `f` or event `n` occurred:

```
df <- structure(list(Trial = 1:3, Trial_time = c("00:00:00.001", "00:00:00.002", 
"00:00:00.003"), A = c("f", "n", "n"), B = c("f", "n", "f"), 
    C = c("f", "f", "n"), D = c("f", "f", "n"), E = c("f", "f", 
    "n")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

How can I establish an interrater reliability score for this kind of rating in R? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a chance-adjusted index of categorical reliability. There are many packages and functions that will do this. For instance, see Gwet's [irrCAC](https://github.com/kgwet/irrCAC/) package or my [agreement](https://github.com/jmgirard/agreement) package. You would treat trials as "objects" of measurement and raters as "sources" of measurement.